# Get the cartesian position vector of a satellite from a TLE file (two line elements)

Tags: python, vector, position, satellite

I have a TLE file associated with a satellite (contains its keplerian coordinates: [TLE_description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7igX.png) such as Eccentricity (degrees), Perigee Argument (degrees), Epoch (year_month_day hour:min:sec) and so on. It looks like this:

'''ISS (ZARYA)
1 25544U 98067A 14273.50403866 .00012237 00000-0 21631-3 0 1790
2 25544 51.6467 297.5710 0002045 126.1182 27.2142 15.50748592907666
I've attached a photo that shows the names of each value in the TLE.'''

From this TLE file, I want to have the Cartesian position vector (X, Y, Z) of the satellite in the satellite fix.

To do this, I tried using the beyond library (from beyond.io.tle import Tle ; from beyond.frames import create_station) to get some Keplerian data, (azimuth, elevation, distance_from_the_station) but all this data is computed with respect to a station, so this isn't the position vector of the satellite but a vector (azimut_station_to_satellite, elevation_station_to_satellite, distance_station_to_satellite) and I can't have the position vector from it. But since I can have a vector, I'm sure there is a way to get directly the position of the satellite from its TLE file.

If it's necessary, I can add a code!
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just a head's up, the photo you uploaded is showing black text against a dark grey background, so it's hard to figure out they key you're using.

Comment: Thank you @LTheriault I'm changing that right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, here's the answer :
I have a TLE like this :

'1 28446U 04041A   19002.21559949 -.00000090  00000-0  00000+0 0  9998
2 28446   0.0198  37.5572 0002596 225.6438 170.9111  1.00271812 52071'

To get the position and/or speed vector of my satellite in the cartesian coordinates, I juste have to do :

```
from sgp4.api import Satrec
from sgp4.api import jday

s = '1 28446U 04041A   19002.21559949 -.00000090  00000-0  00000+0 0  9998'
t = '2 28446   0.0198  37.5572 0002596 225.6438 170.9111  1.00271812 52071'
satellite = Satrec.twoline2rv(s, t)

jd, fr = jday(2019, 1, 1, 11, 59, 33) # I pick an epoch (close to the TLE's)
e, r, v = satellite.sgp4(jd, fr) # e = error, r = position vector, v = speed vector
```

If e = 0 there's no problem, else you get the index of the error.
Credits go to Brandon Rhodes!

Comment: If I understood the sgp4.api code right then to get a sattelite position at exact moment of TLE  starts one better use `satellite.sgp4(satellite.jdsatepoch, satellite.jdsatepochF)` or `satellite.sgp4_tsince(0)`